# Take data from Yahoo Finance and show it in Fragment

Tags: java, android, csv, android-fragments, yahoo-finance

In **Fragment** of my android application I wanna show simple data from **Yahoo Finance** as **price, company name, ticker** etc with the help of **csv**(Comma-Separated Values). I have Error as NullPointerException when I tried to set values to TextView in my FinanceFragment. Can anyone show me correct way to do that or fix my code.

Thanks for any help!

**Activity.java**

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_search_ticker, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText input = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.input_ticker);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

        builder.setPositiveButton("SEARCH TICKER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String SearchTicker = input.getText().toString();

                if(SearchTicker.matches("")) { //Check if EditText is empty / If empty show message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Space is empty. Please try enter again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if(new YahooAsyncTask().execute(SearchTicker) == null){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is no such ticker. Please try enter again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        new YahooAsyncTask().execute(SearchTicker);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

private class YahooAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Stock> {

        LinearLayout Progress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Progress);
        LinearLayout NoInternetConnection = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.NoInternetConnection);
        FrameLayout FragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Sets company info invisible, and progress indicator visible
            Progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NoInternetConnection.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            FragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        protected Stock doInBackground(String... ticker) {
            Stock stock = null;
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                try {
                    stock = YahooFinanceInfo.getStockData(ticker[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("YAHOO_ERROR", e.toString());
                }
            }
            return stock;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Stock stock) {
            Progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (stock != null) {
                // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
                YahooFragment yahooFragment = YahooFragment.newInstance(stock);

                if (findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer) != null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, yahooFragment).commit();
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.FragmentContainer, yahooFragment).commit();
                }
                FragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                NoInternetConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is the NullPointerException happening on?  Additionally, it would help if you posted your XML layout file.

Comment: Hello man! I added LogCat error and xml file to my post. Error was in line tvCompany.setText(stock.getName()); of Fragment. Can you check it again whats wrong?

Comment: In that case, I would say the problem is probably that your stock variable is null.  I would try doing line by line debugging to see if the "stock" variable has a value at that point.  You should set the variable before adding your fragment to the view hierarchy, or use a separate setter for the stock that is called after the view is created.

Comment: Hello @aeskreis again! Now I have NullPointerException here: new GetKeyStatsAsyncTask().execute(ticker); and inside GetKeyStatsAsyncTask method where I initialized my LinearLayout(HeaderProgress, NoInternetConnection).

Comment: As you see from my xml file I have 3 main LinearLayout. First one with ProgressBar and Second one with TextView = "NoInternetConnection". They became visable when there is no network (by default they are invisable). Third LinearLayout with id=fragment_container. All my TextViews are inside of that LinearLayout. I tried to experiment and removed first and second LinearLayouts. After that app started but TextViews was empty. Do you have any ideas why there is conflict with AsyncTask?

Comment: I want to help you but the truth is these are not Android issues.  You are now asking us to debug your application for you, and that's not right.  We aren't the ones who get paid if you complete your project.  Android has great debugging tools which allow you to figure out the source of your NullPointerExceptions.  If you have any Android-specific questions, I would be happy to help, but I'm not going to help you debug NullPointers from code snippets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75982/discussion-between-aeskreis-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).

Comment: You are right man! NullPointerExceptions are always big headache! Now I decided to work with Activity and luckly for me it works fine but still now I have little problems. I have one more question to you. Let me explain it to you.  I made custom AlertDialog with EditText where user write ticker. That ticker I set as parameter of execute. I want to show ToastMessage when user write incorrect ticker and I have null result. I tried this code but app crash when I have null result. Can you say why? I want to show Message when I have null. I updated my post. Can you check it please!

Comment: This is not an Android issue, this is a Java issue.  In Java, when you use a variable without it being initialized, it will crash if you try to execute any method calls on that object.  For instance, if I say String x = null, then try to call x.toString(), this will generate a NullPointerException.  Ensure that all objects that you are calling methods on have values other than null to avoid these exceptions.  It is also unsafe to pass null values into another function, as that function may assume the object you passed is not null , which can also cause exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for information but is it any way to fix it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the error code to be sure, but my guess is it is happening here:

```
LinearLayout HeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.progress_linear_layout);
LinearLayout NoInternetConnection = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.NoInternetConnection);
LinearLayout FragmentContainer = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

this code will be executed before you return onCreateView() which means that getView() probably returns null.

try pulling out these attributes to your activity and initializing them before calling

```
new GetKeyStatsAsyncTask().execute(ticker);
```

**Update**

This is what i meant in my comment:

```
public class FinanceFragment extends Fragment {

TextView tvCompany;
TextView tvCompanyTicker;
TextView tvPrice;
TextView tvPriceChange;
TextView tvPrevClose;
TextView tvOpen;
TextView tvVolume;
TextView tvAvgDailyVolume;
TextView tvDaysRange;
TextView tvYearRange;
TextView tvOneYearTarget;
TextView tvMarketCap;

Stock stock;

String ticker;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finance, container, false);

    tvCompany        = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCompany);
    tvCompanyTicker  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyTicker);
    tvPrice          = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    tvPriceChange    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPriceChange);
    tvPrevClose      = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrevClose);
    tvOpen           = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvOpen);
    tvAvgDailyVolume = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAvgDailyVolume);
    tvVolume         = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvVolume);
    tvDaysRange      = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDaysRange);
    tvYearRange      = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvYearRange);
    tvMarketCap      = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMarketCap);
    tvOneYearTarget  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvOneYearTarget);


    updateView();


    // When application start working, search for Google ticker by default.
    ticker = "GOOG";
    new GetKeyStatsAsyncTask().execute(ticker);

    return view;
}
private void updateView() {
    if(stock == null) {
    // Sets company name, price, etc.
        tvCompany.setText("");
        tvCompanyTicker.setText("");
        tvPrice.setText("");
        tvPriceChange.setText("");
        tvPrevClose.setText("");
        tvOpen.setText("");
        tvAvgDailyVolume.setText("");
        tvVolume.setText("");
        tvDaysRange.setText("");
        tvYearRange.setText("");
        tvMarketCap.setText("");
        tvOneYearTarget.setText("");
    } else {

    // Sets company name, price, etc.
        tvCompany.setText(stock.getName());
        tvCompanyTicker.setText(stock.getTicker());
        tvPrice.setText(stock.getPrice());
        tvPriceChange.setText(stock.getPriceChange());
        tvPrevClose.setText(stock.getPrevClose());
        tvOpen.setText(stock.getOpen());
        tvAvgDailyVolume.setText(stock.getAvgDailyVolume());
        tvVolume.setText(stock.getVolume());
        tvDaysRange.setText(stock.getDaysRange());
        tvYearRange.setText(stock.getYearRange());
        tvMarketCap.setText(stock.getMarketCap());
        tvOneYearTarget.setText(stock.getOneYearTarget());

        // If price change is positive, set TextView to green. Otherwise Red.
        if (stock.getPriceChangeDirection() >= 0)
            tvPriceChange.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.finance_green));
        else
            tvPriceChange.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.finance_red));

    }
}
...
```

And change your onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Stock stock) {
    HeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (stock != null) {
        FragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        updateView();
    } else {
        NoInternetConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

i did not try the code, so there is no guarantee it works

Comment: Hello! I added my Logcat Error to my post! NullPoiterExaption was in line tvCompany.setText(stock.getName()); Can you check it again. Actually I need to make it in Fragment not in Activity. For thats why I am little bit comfused.

Comment: Of course you are right. I meant the Fragment, not the Activity, sorry about that.

Comment: It seems like the system cannot find a view with the id R.id.tvCompany. Could you please edit your post and add the xml layout called fragment_finance.xml ?

Comment: I added xml file to my post. System see them. Problem here for my thinging with new GetKeyStatsAsyncTask().execute(ticker); Whats the best way to give ticker value which I set by default?

Comment: are you sure that stock isnt null when onCreateView is called?

Comment: I think yes but what idea you have?!

Comment: 1. Hold references to your views (private attributes) 2. Write a method that updates the views with appropriate data (keep in mind that stock could be null and update views with default data). 3. Call that method from on create Viewpoint and when you loaded your data and set stock

Comment: I dont understand you exactly. Can you show me example code please. I really confused with all.

Comment: Result still the same. I have NullPointerException but now here: if (stock.getPriceChangeDirection() >= 0) Anyway thanks...

Comment: sry didnt see that one.. moved it down to updateView too

Comment: Hello again. I Tested it and I have again NullPointerException but now here: new GetKeyStatsAsyncTask().execute(ticker); and inside GetKeyStatsAsyncTask method where I initialized my LinearLayout(HeaderProgress, NoInternetConnection) I tried to experiment and removed that LinearLayouts. After that app started but TextViews was empty. Its so sad =( Do you have any ideas why there is conflict with AsyncTask?

Comment: Have you moved your LinearLayout s out to the Fragment? (Where your TextView s are declared too)

Comment: As you see from my xml file I have 3 main LinearLayout. First one with ProgressBar and Second one with TextView = "NoInternetConnection". They became visable when  there is no network (by default they are invisable). Third LinearLayout with id=fragment_container. All my TextViews are inside of that LinearLayout. I just said that I made experiment and removed(deleted) first and second LinearLayouts from xml file and in Fragment where I initialized them.

Comment: What I meant was the Java code.. you declared the LinearLayout s in your GetKeyStatsAsyncTask you should try pulling those declarations out to the Fragment e.g. LinearLayout HeaderProgress; where TextView tvCompany; is and put the other part in your create view. . Eg HeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_linear_layout);

Comment: Are you sure that I need to do that? Inside of GetKeyStatsAsyncTask I have onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods where I used that LinearLayouts. I have red lines in code like: cannot resolve method after declarated LinearLayouts inside the onCreateView. Or I again did something wrong(

Comment: Well the code is executed when an instance of GetKeyStatsAsyncTask is created.. which is in your onCreateView.. as long as you are in onCreateView getView will return null. I'm not completely sure , but very sure this is necessary.

Comment: Hello @Chris Gow are you? NullPointerExceptions are always big headache! Now I decided to work with Activity and luckly for me it works fine but still now I have little problems. I have one more question to you. Let me explain it to you. I made custom AlertDialog with EditText where user write ticker. That ticker I set as parameter of execute. I want to show ToastMessage when user write incorrect ticker and I have null result. I tried this code but app crash when I have null result. Can you say why? I want to show Message when I have null. I updated my post. Can you check it please!